# Error - Custom Data Type as payload with boost::geometry

Tags: c++, templates, boost-geometry

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

template <typename T>
using point_cart_2d = bg::model::point<T, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>;

template <typename T>
using box = bg::model::box<T>;

template <typename T>
using payload = std::pair<box<point_cart_2d<double>>, T>;

template <typename T>
using vec = std::vector<T>;

struct guts {
  int a = 11;
  int b = 22;
};

struct guts_comp {
  using result_type = bool;
  bool operator()(payload<guts> const &v1, payload<guts> const &v2) const {
    return bg::equals(v1.first, v2.first) && v1.second.a == v2.second.a;
  }
};

using rtree = bgi::rtree<payload<guts>,
                         bgi::rstar<16>,
                         bgi::indexable<payload<guts>>,
                         guts_comp>;

int main() {
  vec<payload<guts>> v = {{{{1.0, 1.0}, {7.0, 4.0}}, {2, 3}}};
  rtree              rt;
  // the poem starts here
  for (const auto &k : v) {
    rt.insert(k);
  }
  // or here
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), bgi::inserter(rt));
}
```

I'm trying to use boost::geometry with a custom Type, I have defined a custom type and an operator() to compare the std::pair I'll put inside my rtree but I still receive errors and this doesn't compile .

I think this should just work, but it doesn't, I have no idea why after reading the docs of the library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real stumbling block was a missing include. I'd suggest adding

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/indexable.hpp>
```

Meanwhile, a lot of what you wrote is redundant as the default [IndexableGetter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html#geometry.reference.spatial_indexes.boost__geometry__index__rtree.indexablegetter) and [EqualTo](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html#geometry.reference.spatial_indexes.boost__geometry__index__rtree.equalto) parameters already deal with your choice of payload.

My suggested simplified program therefore would look like this:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea01023f42a485f)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/indexable.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <utility>

struct guts {
    int a = 11;
    int b = 22;
};

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = bg::index;

using point = bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>;
using box = bg::model::box<point>;

using payload = std::pair<box, guts>;
using rtree = bgi::rtree<payload, bgi::rstar<16>>;

int main() {
    std::vector v {
        payload { box { {1.0, 1.0}, {7.0, 4.0} }, guts {2, 3} }
    };

    rtree rt(v);
    for (const auto& k : v)
        rt.insert(k);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), bgi::inserter(rt));
}
```

> ### Note:
>
> Was ignoring `guts::b` really the intent?
>
> In that case, consider simply adding the inline operator overload:
>
> ```
> struct guts {
>     int a = 11;
>     int b = 22;
>
>     bool operator==(guts const& other) const { return a == other.a; }
> };
> ```

Comment: the intent was to design and use a custom type where the "equal to" only takes into account some specific fields . Thank you for your answer, I also had to use the `BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS` macro for my code to compile, this is a behaviour that is not documented anywhere and I still don't know why I had to do that since it's supposed to be a templated library .